# Servlet POST Data is clipped depending on caller

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu, apache2

I've written a Servlet which simply logs the whole raw stream of an POST-Request into a file. Very simple. Works on my development machine fine. If I deploy that on my UBUNTO-Server with Tomcat 5.5 and Apache2 I get following strange results:

If I post something from localhost directly to the "tomcat" everything works fine.

If I post something from localhost via a local apache, only 8K of data come in.

If I post something from exteral only 1.5K come in.

I checked every config-file for any limit I could find by research, but there isn't any limit.

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you put your code here ? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a networking component that truncates "large" requests? Maybe a firewall with some misconfigured QOS settings?

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I'm not exactly sure, which of the limits causes the behaviour, but I'd recommend to explicitly set LimitRequestFieldSize (to let's say 9K) & LimitRequestLine (to let's say 12K), because both default to 8190 (roughly you 8K), since your checks already indicate, that the Apache WS seems to cause the problem. (see also [HTTPD Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody))

The proposed new values are completly arbitrary, but should differ in order to find out, which of the two really causes the problem 8-).

When you say "from external", I guess there is an additional WebServer involved.

Hope that helps !